# Count the number of rows for each file along with the file name in Talend

Tags: talend, data-integration

I have built a job that reads the data from a file, and based on the unique data of a particular columns, splits the data set into many files.

I am able to acheive the requirement by the below job :

[image]

Now from this job which is splitting the output into multiple files, what I want is to add a sub job which would give me two columns.

In the first column I want the name of the files that I created in my main job and in the second column, I want the count of number of rows each created output file has.

To achive this I used tflowmeter and to catch the result of count i used the tFlowmeterCatcher, which is giving me correct result for the count of each rows for the correspoding output files, but is giving the last file name in all the files that i have generated for the counts.

How can I get the correct file names and the corresponding row count.

Comment: Can you use `(String)globalMap.get("tFileInputPositional_1_CURRENT_FILE")` to get the current filename in the second flow? Just add it as a value in `tMap_2`.

Comment: @tobi6 when I use the global parameter that you suggessted it is giving me null value. What I had used was ((String)globalMap.get("row7.newColumn1")) parameter, but it is giving me the last file name for all the unique records. Can you help with some other logic

Comment: Ok, I should have taken `(String)globalMap.get("tFileInputPositional_1_CURRENT_FILE")` there, but this won't work as well, because tFlowMeterCatcher is executed after the upper job. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to generate files each having the name of the files that I created in my main job and in the second column, I want the count of number of rows each created output file has.

Comment: How do you generate the filename in `tFileOutputDelimited_1` now? Maybe you could use a **tJavaFlex** component to count the rows and store filename and row count.

Comment: I have used the ((String)globalMap.get("row7.newColumn1"))+".txt" to generate the multiple output files.
can you provide code snippet for your logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the following directions, your job will in the end have additional components like so:

[image: Extended flow for row count and filename]

Use a **tJavaFlex** directly after the **tFileOutputDelimited** on main. It should look like this:

```
Start Code: int countRows = 0;
Main Code:  countRows = countRows + 1;
End Code:   globalMap.put("rowCount", countRows);
```

Connect this component **OnComponentOk** with the first component of a new subjob. This subjob holds a **tFixedFlowInput**, a **tJavaRow** and a **tBufferOutput**.

The **tFixedFlowInput** is just here so that the **OnComponentOk** can be connected, nothing has to be altered. In **tJavaRow** you put the following:

```
output_row.filename = (String)globalMap.get("row7.newColumn"); 
//or whatever is your row variable where the filename is located

output_row.rowCount = (Integer)globalMap.get("rowCount");
```

In the schema, add the following elements:

[image: Flow variables filename and rowCount]

Simply add a **tBufferOutput** now at the end of the first subjob.

Now, create another new subjob with the components **tBufferInput** and whatever components you may need to process and store the data. Connect the very first component of your job with a **OnSubjobOk** with the **tBufferInput** component. I used a **tLogRow** to show the result (with my randomly created fake data):

```
.---------------+--------.
|      LogFileData       |
|=--------------+-------=|
|filename       |rowCount|
|=--------------+-------=|
|fileblerb1.txt |27      |
|fileblerb29.txt|14      |
|fileblerb44.txt|20      |
'---------------+--------'
```

*NOTE:* Keep in mind that if you add a header to the file (`Include Header` checked in **tFileOutputDelimited**), the job might need to be changed (simply set `int countRows = 1;` or whatever you would need). I did not test this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tFileproperties component to store file-name generated in a intermediate excel after first sub-job and use this excel in your second sub-job.

Thanks!

Comment: What would be the flow in case i use the tFileProperties component.