# Talend DB to JSON OutPut file

Tags: json, database, etl, talend, bi-tool

I am stuck in one job of Talend. I am using Talend for migrating the DB fields into a JSON file.

I am successfully able to do the job but the JSON format which I am getting is an array format, not the customized format like address fields are not coming under parent child relationship.

In my job I am reading the data from file storing it into db and then generating the JSON file.

Current JSON output:

```
[ 
  { 
    "name":"test", 
    "age":"21", 
    "phone":"12345678", 
    "city":"india", 
    "state":India", 
    "country":"India" 
  } 
]
```

Desired JSON output:

```
[
  {
    "profile": { 
        "name":"test", 
        "age":"21", 
        "phone":"12345678", 
    },
    "address": { 
        "city":"india", 
        "state":"India", 
        "country":"India" 
    }
  }
]
```

There are majorly two issue with my job :

- JSON customised format
- No of row per file

[image]

Can any one please help me out in this.

Comment: Please post JSON code and how you want the JSON to look like. For [numbers of rows look here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37373455/5191221), might help.

Comment: current output: 
[ { 
   "name":"test",
   "age":"21",
   "phone":"12345678",
   "city":"india",
   "state":India",
   "country":"India"

  }
]


desired output: 
[ { 
  "profile":
   {
   "name":"test",
   "age":"21",
   "phone":"12345678",
   }
   "address":
   {
   "city":"india",
   "state":India",
   "country":"India" 
   }
]

Answer (score 1):

**tFileOutputJSON** seems to be a bit inflexible when it comes to structuring the JSON output.

Lets take a **tWriteJSONField** component instead. In this component, you need an input schema like:

- profile (will be empty)
- name
- age
- phone
- address (will be empty)
- city
- state
- country

Now set an output column first. Select *Remove root node*. Then configure the JSON tree like this:

[image: tWriteJSONField JSON Tree config page]

Here is my output (I took your example data):

```
{
    "profile": {
        "name": "test",
        "age": "21",
        "phone": "123456789"
    },
    "address": {
        "city": "india",
        "state": "India",
        "country": "India"
    }
}
```

It should be possible to work from here on to get the desired output.